# What's "$\mathbb Z = (1)$ is cyclic"?

Tags: abstract-algebra

As I understand it, $(1)$ is a cyclic group with $1$ being its generator. So, $1^n$ with $n \in \mathbb N$ generates $\mathbb Z^+$ , but what about $\mathbb Z^{-1}$ ? Do we say $(1)$ is a cyclic group with two operations $(+, -)$ defined on it so that $\mathbb Z = (1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we say that a set generates a group, it means that every element of the group is a product of these elements *and their inverse*. Otherwise it generally won't be a group.

Comment: a product in the sense of the group operation. if the group operation is $\circ$, then $g^n = \underbrace{g \circ \ldots \circ g}_{n}$. here the group operation is the addition, and $g$ is the integer $1$, hence $g^n$ should be read $\underbrace{1 + \ldots + 1}_{n}$ which equals the integer $n$, and its inverse (for the group operation) is $-n$

Comment: ...ok ? What does that have to do with my answer ?

Comment: it was unclear, it has to do with the question

Comment: the term "product" was highly unclear in the context !  that's why I gave the needed precisions

Comment: One would think that calling $\Bbb Z$'s $+$ "product" is rather strange.

Comment: On the other hand, the OP writes $1^n$, which *is* indeed rather strange.

Answer (score 0):

In algebra, when you say that a set $S$ generates some structure $A$, you mean that any element of $A$ can be represented as repeated applications of operations of the structure in question to elements of $S$.

In your case, the structure is a group. A group has not only the binary operation, but also the inverse (and, technically, the identity element, considered as a nullary operation). So, $\{1\}$ indeed generates $\mathbb{Z}$, since the inverse of it (which is $-1$) and powers of inverse are also allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about an abelian group $G$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, (intuitively "as a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}$"), then cyclic means that $G$ is generated by one element $g\in G$ (as an abelian group) and this translates to $G$ being generated by $g$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, which means simply
$ G = \langle \;g \;\rangle_{\mathbb{Z}} = \{n\cdot g \,; \,n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$
where $n\cdot g$ is defined as $g$ composed with itself $n$-times with respect to the group operation of $G$. If G is written additively as in the case $G=\mathbb{Z}$, then  $n\cdot g = g+\ldots + g$ exactly $n$-times.

This approach helps to understand why every group of the form $C_m = \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic with generator 1, since for all $g\in C_m$ we have $g=n\cdot 1$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Of course, since $-1\in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $-g\in \langle\, g\, \rangle_{\mathbb{Z}}$.